# Measure and limsup and liminf

Tags: measure-theory

> Given a ring of set $R$, $\mu$ a measure on $R$ and if $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of sets in $R$ for which
>
> $\bigcap_{i=n}^{\infty}E_i$ for $n=1,2,...$ and $\lim \inf E_n \in R$ then $\mu(\lim \inf E_n)\leq \lim \inf \mu(E_n)$
>
> $\bigcup_{i=n}^{\infty} E_i$ for $n=1,2,...$ and $\lim \sup E_n \in R$ then $\mu(\lim \sup E_n)\geq \lim\sup  \mu(E_n)$

How can I prove these results? I don't know how to begin. I know that it is a direct use of the definition but I only know how to work with $\lim\sup$ for set point by point, not as a whole.

When I posted this question I had no idea about how to begin the problem. Now, I have resolved my doubts (someone in this forum give me an advice), but I can not post what I have done if nothing have been done, not because I was not thinking in the problem, but because nothing come to my mind to solve it.

In this kind of cases (in which you really don't have any idea about how to attack the problem) I am not sure how to post here. Since I need a hint, but could happen someone thinks that I want that others solve my homework (which is not my case).

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Do you know how to define $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of sets? If so, then you can just mimic the proof of continuity of measures found in any measure theory book.

Comment: I don't know why you want to closed the post. I really don't know how to solve the problem, it may be trivial but i am not seeing  it. At the moment i am reading again the proof of the theorem you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not trying to close the post. I actually upvoted your post to keep it not negative. I was just asking what you did or did not know about how to do it. I'd be happy to type a solution, but it is better for you to do it yourself, especially because this really follows from elementary properties of measures. If you're just starting measure theory, you will have to get used to and understand arguments used to prove this, so it's good to see how much you can do on your own. I gave you a hint on where to look. If you still don't see it, I will answer the question explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21395/discussion-between-yotas-trejos-and-moya).

Comment: I got that $\mu(\lim\inf E_n)=\lim \mu(\bigcap_{i=n}^{\infty} E_i)$. Then since $\bigcap_{i=n}^{\infty} E_i\subset E_k$ with $k\geq n$ then $\mu(\bigcap_{i=n}^{\infty} E_i)\leq \mu(E_k)$ for $k\geq n$ which implies that $\mu(\bigcap_{i=n}^{\infty} E_i)\leq \inf\{ \mu(E_k): k\geq n\}$ and finally $\lim_{n}\mu(\bigcap_{i=n}^{\infty} E_i)\leq \lim\inf_n E_n$. Am I right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Defining $F_k=\bigcap_{n=k}^\infty E_n$ we can see that $F_1\subset F_2\subset \dots,$ which implies that
$$\mu(\lim_k F_k) = \lim_k \mu(F_k)$$
by continuity of the measures. But
$$\lim_k F_k = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty F_k = \lim\inf E_n.$$
This is a useful result. That $\bigcap_{n=k}^\infty E_n\subset E_k$ for every $k\geq n$ implies $\mu(\bigcap_{n=k}^\infty E_n)\leq \mu(E_k)$ for every $k \geq n$, hence
$$\mu(\bigcap_{n=k}^\infty E_n)\leq \inf\{\mu(E_k): k\geq n\}.$$
Taking the limit over $k$ and using $\lim_k \bigcap_{n = k}^\infty E_n = \lim_k F_k = \lim\inf E_n,$ we get $\mu(\lim\inf E_n)\leq \lim\inf \mu(E_n).$

Analogously, using the continuity from above measures we can get the other result.

Comment: The above proof will not work for the second result. If you define $F_n = \cup_{i=n}^{\infty} E_i$, then $\{ F_n \}$ is a decreasing sequence of sets. However, for decreasing sequences you need to know that at least one of the $F_n$ has finite measure to use continuity from above (see Halmos, Measure Theory, theorem 9.E). This would be true in a finite measure space but is false in general.

Answer (score 10):

The second statement is false.

Consider the sequence $E_n = [n-1,n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure. Every non-negative real number is in one and only one of the $E_n$, so $\limsup E_n = \emptyset$. However, we have $\mu(E_n) = 1$ for all $n$, so $\limsup \mu(E_n) =1$. Therefore $\mu ( \limsup E_n) < \limsup \mu(E_n)$.