# Hilbert space finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

We are in $L^2([0;1];\mathbb{R})$. Let $F$ be a closed subspace of $L^2([0;1];\mathbb{R})$ which verify that for each function $f \in F$, $f \in C^0([0;1])$. We have already proved that $||.||_2$ and $||.||_\infty$ are equivalent norm of $F$. Moreover, if we note $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ a Hilbert basis of $F$, we have proved that :

$\forall x \in [0;1] \quad \exists K_x > 0 \quad \sum_{i \in I} |e_i(x)|^2 \leq K_x$

And I have to deduce that $F$ is a finite dimensional space.

I wanted to prove that $I$ is finite, and then the proof will be ended. To do that, I imagine that I have to use the hypothesis that $e_i$ is continuous and $||e_i||_2 = 1$. 
But I tried several things and nothing have worked yet.

Someone could help me ? :)

Comment: How $\parallel \cdot \parallel_2$ and $\parallel \cdot \parallel_\infty$ can be equivalent ?

Comment: Because $F$ is finite dimensional, all norms are equivalent. $F$ is only a subspace of $L^2$ here after all.

Comment: I guess this is due to the closeness of $F$. My bad

Comment: What does $e_i(x)$ mean in this context? As $e_i$ is an element of $L^2$, it is not a function, but rather an equivalence class of functions. When you integrate, this is not a problem, but evaluating at a single point seems not well-defined to me.

Comment: Here $F$ is included in $C^0([0,1])$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft : I think, as each function $f \in F$ is continuous, if we take $g=e_i$ almost everywhere (and $g \in F$, in particular : $\overline{g} = \overline{e_i}$ in $L^2$ and $g, e_i$ continuous as elements of F), then $e_i = g$ because the both function are continuous. I think, when we take $f \in F$, actually we are taking $f$ which represents $\overline{f}$ in $L^2$, and $f$ continuous. So, the two notion coincide and are well-defined in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $||\cdot||_2$ and $||\cdot||_\infty$ are equivalent, there exists $C>0$ such that $||e_i||_\infty\leq C||e_i||_2=C$ holds for all $i\in I$.
By definition, this means $|e_i(x)|\leq C$ holds for all $i\in I$ and $x\in[0,1]$.

For $i\in I$ define $U_i:\{x\in[0,1]:|e_i(x)|\geq\frac12\}$. Then
$$||e_i||_2=
\sqrt{\int_0^1|e_i(x)|^2dx}=
\sqrt{\int_{U_i}|e_i(x)|^2dx+\int_{U_i^c}|e_i(x)|^2dx}\leq
\sqrt{C^2\lambda(U_i)+\frac14\lambda(U_i^c)}.$$
Here $\lambda$ represents the Lebesgue measure.
Notice that $\lambda(U_i^c)=1-\lambda(U_i)$.
Since $||e_i||_2=1$, it follows that
$$C^2\lambda(U_i)+\frac14(1-\lambda(U_i))\geq1,\\
(C^2-\frac14)\lambda(U_i)\geq\frac34.$$
Notice that this means that $C^2>\frac14$.
Therefore, we find a lower bound $L$ on $\lambda(U_i)$.

Assume for the contrary that $I$ is infinite.
Your result:
$$\forall x\in[0,1]:\sum_{i\in I}|e_i(x)|^2<\infty$$
implies that $\limsup U_i=\emptyset$.
However, we also have $\limsup \lambda(U_i)\geq L>0$.
This is a contradiction ([Measure and limsup and liminf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162623/measure-and-limsup-and-liminf)) so $I$ must be finite.

Comment: The existence of $C$ follows from the fact that in a normed vector space, two norms are equivalent iff they are uniformly equivalent.... BTW  $(C^2-1/4)\lambda (U_i)\geq 3/4$ implies $C\geq 1$ because  $0\leq \lambda (U_i)\leq 1.$ But this not affect the argument, because the point is that the constant $K=C^2-1/4$ is positive, so $\lambda (U_i)\geq 3/4K$ for all $i.$...............+1