# Proving properties of a family of measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Let $m$ be a lebesgue measure and $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a family of measurable sets on $[0,1]$,and $F=\{x:\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \exists k\geq n \text{ s.t } x\in A_k  \}$

Prove the following:

1. $F=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$
2. if $m(A_n)>\delta>0$ for all $n$ then $m(F)>\delta$
3. if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m(A_n)<\infty$ then $m(f)=0$
4. there is a familly $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ s.t $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m(A_n)=\infty$ and $m(F)=0$

1) I started with taking and element from the RHS and LHS and show it bidirectional contained to prove the equality.

Let $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ that mean the for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the element $x\in\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ which means that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there are some $k\geq n$ such that $x\in A_k$ but this is the definition of $F$ so $x\in F$.

Now to take $x\in F$ and show that $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ seems to be the same claims as before

2) I have thought about way to start using the definition that $E$ is lebesgue measurable then for all $A$ we have $m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+^*(A\cap E^C)$ but I do not have much to say on the compliment of the set $A_k$

3) I tried using the subadditive of the measure and the fact the a bounded set a measure $0$ but did not manage

4) I do not have a clear idea how to approach this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2)Νote that $F=\limsup_nA_n$

Use the inequality $$m(\limsup_nA_n) \geq \limsup_nm(A_n)$$

3) It is the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

4)Take the sets $A_n=[0,\frac{1}{n}]$

Comment: So the first one is correct?

Comment: @newhere yes it is

Comment: in 2 we can use the inequality just if $A_n$ is of finite measure. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162623/measure-and-limsup-and-liminf/1163407

Comment: @newhere all $A_n$ are subsets of $[0,1]$ so they have finite measure

Comment: Sorry, correct, I meant for what I defined $F_k=\cup_{n=k}^{\infty}A_n$ to use continuity from below I have to show that $m(F_1)<\infty$ and $F_1$ can be infinte

Comment: @newhere no it cannot because $F_1 \subseteq [0,1]$ since every $A_n$ is

Comment: But if $m(A_n)\leq 1$ for each $n$ the then if $F_k=\cup_{n=k}^{\infty}A_n$ then $m(F_1)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n=\infty$ by subadditivity

Comment: @newhere,,  This does not tell the $m(F_1)=+\infty$...$F_1$ has finite measure..if you accept my answer, you do not have to give me a bounty..because it is not worth it

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to be sure I got the correct answer

Comment: @newhere if it is possible you can cancel the bounty ,if you want..it is not such a difficult question to deserve a bounty especially that big..