# Why the Bernoulli measure is the Lebesgue measure viewed on the numbers written in basis two?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I can't understand this sentence:
the Bernoulli measure with $p_1 = p_2 = 1/2 $
is nothing else than Lebesgue measure viewed on the
numbers written in basis two.

I'm interested in the case of unit segment $[0,1]$.

Given the set $A=\{0,1\}$, let be $M=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. A generic element of $M$ is $m=(m_1,...,m_k,...)$ The $\sigma$-algebra is defined by the generator set $A_i^j=\{m \in M\, : \,m_i = j\}$ with $j=0,1$ and let $p_j=1/2$, for $j=0,1$.

The measure is defined by
$$\mu(A^j_i)=p_j.$$

How can i show that this measure is the same of Lebesgue measure on the segment $[0,1]$? Where am i wrong in the following example?

The number between $0$ and $0.5$ are all the sequence $m$ with $0$ in the first position, that is the set
$A_1^0$. So $\mu(A_1^0) = 1/2$ and this is ok with Lebesgue measure because $|0.5-0|=1/2.$
But what about the set, for example, $A_2^1$? Even the measure of this set is $1/2$ but it represents the sequence like $01000... ;11000...; 11100...;...$ with $1$ in the second position, which corresponds to the numbers $0.25000; 0.75000 ; 0.87500;...$. But the Lebesgue measure of this set is zero, while $\mu( A_2^1)=1/2$. Why this?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: in the following I've used the same symbol $\mu$ to represent the measure in the space $\{0,1\}^{{\mathbb N}}$ and it induced measure in $[0,1]$. Note also that numbers that have a digital terminal representation are necessarily countable, and so it total measure is zero, so repeated number representations can be ignored in the evaluation of measures.*

Pick some $x\in[0,1]$ then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ note that $f_n(x):=2^{-n}\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor$ have a terminal representation of $n$ digits in basis $2$, that is $f_n(x)= \sum_{k=1}^n x_k 2^{-k}$ for some $x_k\in\{0,1\}$, so

$$
\mu([f_n(x),f_n(x)+2^{-n}])=\mu(\{m\in\{0,1\}^{{\mathbb N}}:m_k=x_k \text{ for each }k\in\{1,\ldots ,n\}\})=2^{-n}
$$

because $2^{-n}\equiv 0.\overbrace{0\ldots 0}^{n \text{ times }}111\ldots $ where the latter is written in base $2$. Now note that

$$ 
\begin{align*}
f_n(x)+2^{-n}&=2^{-n}\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor +2^{-n}\\&=2^{-n}( \lfloor 2^nx\rfloor+1)\\&=2^{-n}\lfloor 2^nx+1\rfloor\\&=2^{-n}\lfloor 2^n(x+2^{-n})\rfloor\\&=f_n(x+2^{-n})
\end{align*}
$$

so $f_n(x)+2^{-n}$ also have a terminal representation of $n$ digits in base $2$. Therefore for arbitrary $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $x\leqslant y$ the integer $ \lfloor 2^n y\rfloor- \lfloor 2^n x\rfloor$ gives the number of intervals of the form $[f_n(r),f_n(r)+ 2^{-n}]$ between $f_n(x)$ and $f_n(y)$ (with overlapping extremes), that is $(f_n(x),f_n(y)]$ is the disjoint union

$$
(f_n(x),f_n(y)]= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\lfloor 2^n y\rfloor- \lfloor 2^n x\rfloor}(f_n(x)+(j-1)2^{-n},f_n(x)+ j2^{-n}]
$$

Hence

$$
\mu([x,y])= \lim_{n \to \infty }\mu ([f_n(x),f_n(y)])= \lim_{n\to \infty }2^{-n}( \lfloor 2^ny\rfloor- \lfloor 2^n x\rfloor)=y-x
$$

where the first equality above is just an application of the continuity from below and above of measures (take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162623/measure-and-limsup-and-liminf/1163407)). Thus $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I can't understand the first equality... $\mu([f_n(x),f_n(x)+2^{−n}])=\mu(\{m\ in \{0,1\}^N\,:\, m_k=x_k \,for\, each \,k\in \{1,…,n\}\})$.
All the real numbers between $f_n(x),f_n(x)+2^{−n}$ have the same first n digits equal?

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro suppose that $f_5(x)=0.01010$ in basis two, then $f_5(x)+2^{-5}=0.01010+0.0000011111...=0.0101011111...=0.01011$, so $[f_5(x),f_5(x)+2^{-5}]\equiv \{m\in\{0,1\}^{{\mathbb N}}: m_1=0,m_2=1,m_3=0,m_4=1,m_5=0\}$

Comment: Ok, nice.  Another question: why the integer $\lfloor 2^n y\rfloor− \lfloor 2^n x\rfloor$ gives me the number of the interval of that form?

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro I edited the answer to show that $f_n(x)+2^{-n}$ haves also a terminal representation in base $2$. This shows that $2^{-n}( \lfloor 2^nx\rfloor+ m)$ for any integer $m$ have a terminal representation of $n$ digits (it decimal part, if $m$ is too long then the resulting number will be bigger than one)

Comment: Ok, there's something that still I can't understand..but, however, what about my example? I am looking for some "pragmatic"..

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro I edited again the answer giving more details about your previous comment. About your last comment: your conclusion is wrong, the Lebesgue measure of $A_2^1$ is not zero, it is not countable, note that $A_2^1=[0.01,0.01111...]_2 \cup [0.11,0.111...]_2=[0.01,0.1]_2 \cup [0.11,1]_2=[1/4,1/2] \cup [3/4,1]$

Comment: I really thank you, I'am reading all your comment and your edits. Thank you again, you are special! :P

Comment: sorry, one more thing... I will not pretend the calculus, but is it true that $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k 2^{-k} = 2^{-n} \lfloor 2^n x \rfloor  $ ?

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro let $x\in[0,1]$ then $x= \sum_{k\geqslant 1}x_k 2^{-k}\equiv 0.x_1x_2x_3...$ where the later is the digital representation of $x$ in base $2$, therefore $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k 2^{-k} = 2^{-n} \lfloor 2^n x \rfloor$